# Rails: Array of strings and links appear on same line when iterated

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, erb

I have an array:

```
        <% array = [
          "This is a string, ",
          link_to("And this is a link", root_path),
          ", And I want it all to be on the same line!",
          "
          
          This part, I want on the new line!"
        ] %>
```

*(Note: the last item in the array intentionally has a new line which is a `\n` when consulted in the console)*

And I want to be able to iterate on this array and display it in my view as such:

```
      <div class="post-content">
        <% array.each do |c| %>
         <%= c %>
        <% end %>
      </div>
```

I am using the css:

```
.post-content {
    white-space: pre-line;
}
```

When executed, each item in the array is displayed on a new line.  The inspector looks like this:

```
      <div class="post-content">
        " This is a string,  "
        <a href="/">And this is a link</a>
        " , And I want it all to be on the same line! This part, I want on the new line! "
      </div>
```

I understand that each item in the array is being displayed as a different element. Is my understanding correct?
If so, is there a way that I can iterate through the array and display all items in the array as one element?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

The solution I found is to use `safe_join` :

```
        <div class="post-content">
          <%= safe_join(array) %>
        </div>
```